# Rename cu.usbserial-1410 on macOS

Tags: usb

Is it possible to rename, e.g., [cu.usbserial-1410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu) to something else?

I have to connect multiple Arduino's and right now the order is rather important.
Being able to set a fixed name would help a lot.

Comment: Someone on [https://apple.stackexchange.com/](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) might have more chance of answering this. It's an OS X problem not an Arduino problem.

Comment: Depending on your application, can't you ask the Arduinos for their "name" to recognize them? Relying on the PC's names of the interfaces will only work to some degree.

Comment: @thebusybee yeah, I think I probably will do that so it also works on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Proposal:

Instead of trying to convince the PC's OS (be it macOS, Windows, or Linux) to use a fixed name for interfaces that connect specific Arduinos, add a identifying feature to your Arduino application. Then from the PC application ask each connected Arduino for its name to identify it.